# Check if words of a list occur in a list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have a list of dictionaries and five lists of words. I want to look if the words of the lists occur in the dictionaries. Therefore I used the the following code:

```
import json

with open("pbs_words_results_test.json") as json_file:
    data_words = json.load(json_file)
```

List of dictionaries:

```
[{"query": "love", "title": "How this reporter learned to love nosy questions", "datetime": "Oct 21, 2020 08:27 PM EDT", "snippet": "Our October 2020 pick for the PBS NewsHour-New York Times book club is Paul Tough's \u201cHelping Children Succeed.\u201d", "url": "https://www.pbs.org/newshour/arts/how-this-reporter-learned-to-love-nosy-questions", "news_platform": "pbs"}, {"query": "love", "title": "Britney Spears shows love for #FreeBritney in court filing", "datetime": "Sep 04, 2020 12:06 AM EDT", "snippet": "Britney Spears is welcoming public scrutiny of the court conservatorship that has allowed her father to control her life and money for 12 years.", "url": "https://www.pbs.org/newshour/arts/britney-spears-shows-love-for-freebritney-in-court-filing", "news_platform": "pbs"}, {"query": "love", "title": "WATCH: Trump says QAnon conspiracists 'love our country'", "datetime": "Aug 19, 2020 09:54 PM EDT", "snippet": "... than 1,000 times in just 30 minutes. \"Holy Smokin Q,\" another tweeted. \"Our President was asked 2 questions about the Qanon movement TODAY!! We LOVE you President Trump.\" On Parler, a right-wing platform popular with some Trump supporters, one Qanon supporter posted a photo of Trump and a ...", "url": "https://www.pbs.org/newshour/politics/watch-live-trump-holds-white-house-news-conference-4", "news_platform": "pbs"},
```

lists of words:

```
with open("anger.json", "r") as read_file:
    anger = json.load(read_file)

with open("sadness.json", "r") as read_file:
    sadness = json.load(read_file)

with open("disgust.json", "r") as read_file:
    disgust = json.load(read_file)

with open("enjoyment.json", "r") as read_file:
    enjoyment = json.load(read_file)

with open("enjoyment.json", "r") as read_file:
    fear = json.load(read_file)
```

enjoyment:

```
["love", "relief", "contentment", "amusement", "joy", "pride", "excitement", "peace", "satisfaction", "compassion", "liefde", "opluchting", "tevredenheid", "amusement", "vreugde", "trots", "opwinding", "vrede", "mededogen"]
```

Then is used this for-loop to iterate through the list of words and if words are in data_words it will add an extra item to the dictionaries:

```
for words in enjoyment:
    if words in data_words:
       data_words["emotions"] = "enjoyment"
```

For some reason it doesn't seem to find the words in the dictionaries.

Comment: could you show small examples of what `data_words` and `enjoyment` actually contain?

Comment: data_words [{"query": "love", "title": "How. enjoyment ["love", "relief", "contentment",

Comment: @roet--question code clarifications should be placed in question post rather than comments to make it easier for potential responders to find.  That said, not sure if I understand the structure of data_words.  Is it a list containing a dictionary?  The syntax in your example is incorrect.

Comment: Okay thanks for letting me know. It is a list made out of dictionaries of articles.

Comment: @roet great, can you please edit the question to add those snippets in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your variable `data_words` is a list of dictionaries.

```
for words in enjoyment:
    if words in data_words: # Line 2: This condition will never be True.
       data_words["emotions"] = "enjoyment"
```

In your code snippet, in Line 2, your condition tries to match the contents of the list containing *dictionaries* to a single string.

Note that This will always be False, because a string and a dictionary are different (even if the dictionary itself may contain the string. the code will not search through the dictionary automatically for you. The `in` check only checks if the list directly contains the item (the `words` variable in this case) you're searching for.)

---

What you need to do instead then, is take each dictionary from your list, and search for your word *inside* this dictionary's snippet.

```
# one dictionary at a time from the list of dicts
for dictionary in data_words: 
    # take one word from your list of words
    for word in enjoyment: 
        # word found in snippet.
        if word in dictionary['snippet']: 
            dictionary['emotions'] = "enjoyment" # Assuming that you want the emotions to be captured in the same dictionary. change as necessary.
```

Note that you can also use the `any` function to make this shorter.

```
for dictionary in data_words:
    if any(word in dictionary['snippet'] for word in enjoyment):
        dictionary['emotions'] = "enjoyment"
```